# Basement Bath floor

Tags: bathroom, tile, basement, laminate

I'm putting Platon drain board on the slab of my basement because I'm concerned with humidity and moisture.  Then I top it with laminate.  What should I do with the bathroom?

Can tile be put on top of Platon?

If not, should I not put Platon but go with Schluter Ditra and tile?

Or should go with Platon and some other flooring such as laminate, etc.

Do people have any opinions on this?

Comment: The installation instructions don't say anything about installing a tile floor over it, so I would say you probably don't want to do it.  It says you can lay a floating floor right on top of it, but if using vinyl, carpet, or hardwood you should lay plywood or OSB sub-floor on top first.  I would go with Ditra if your going to tile, it is made for that after all.

Answer (score 3):

The installation instructions don't say anything about installing a tile floor over it, so I would say you probably don't want to do it.

It says you can lay a floating floor right on top of it, but if using vinyl, carpet, or hardwood you should lay plywood or OSB sub-floor on top first. I would go with Ditra if your going to tile, it is made for that after all.

*Comment converted to answer*